Change the typing color in inputs python
I was wondering if there is a way to change the color of the text that user is typing in the input.
input("Type here: ")
For the 'Type here' I changed the color but when the user is typing, the text is always white.
Are there any solutions?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458685/python-colored-text-on-input-statement
